# VB and VBA Program Settings are invisible in RegEdit but accessible via VBA

Tags: vba, windows, registry

I got a new laptop with 64-bit Windows 10 Home (version 1803) and 32-bit Office 365 (version 1811) installed.

I can use `SaveSetting` and `GetSetting` commands via VBA with no problem, VBA saves and reads everything properly.

But I cannot see **VB and VBA Program Settings** via RegEdit (not under `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software`, not anywhere else):
[image]

The key just does not exist.

I tried both `C:\Windows\regedit.exe` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe` - neither showed the key.

I created VB and VBA Program Settings with a couple of sections and keys to test via RegEdit - VBA read them all perfectly, but when I changed them via `SaveSetting`, RegEdit did not show updated values. `GetSetting` did. After I delete them via `DeleteSetting`, VBA no longer shows them but RegEdit still does.

I ran a search for the key added via `SaveSetting`, it came up with no results.

I cannot see VB and VBA Program Settings via PowerShell or PowerShell(x86) either. I cannot see them in the text file that I export the registry to.

It seems like a Windows or Office bug. Any ideas how I can see actual values under VB and VBA Program Settings via RegEdit?

Comment: I just tested (Office 2010 x64, Win10 x64) - settings *do* appear in RegEdit.

Comment: For me it's also working fine. You probably do not look at the right place in the registry. Look [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/using_the_getsetting_savesetting_functions/) where to find the settings in the registry you placed with SaveSetting.

Comment: There's a Wow6432Node key. Might want to look into that, too.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks, I looked into Wow6432Node - no luck, Like I said I also ran a search through the whole registry as well as its exported version - the key is nowhere in it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have no idea what it was but reinstalling MS Office fixed the issue. My original Office was pre-installed on the laptop, courtesy of Lenovo. I uninstalled it, then installed it from Microsoft website, and everything seems now back to normal.